# Authenticate custom user class in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, custom-authentication

I have a system that uses the built in Identity system to authenticate users for the admin section.

I want to let other users login through external web service but was wondering if I could create a different user class for them and still take advantage of built in functionality such as [Authorize] attribute.

Let's say the custom class looks like this:

```
public class CustomUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
}
```

I would add this user to a role, for example "customUser" so in a controller I would like to use the authorize attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="customUser")]
public ActionResult DoStuff()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Is this possible, have a custom user class and manually authenticate him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just inherit from `ApplicationUser` (or whatever you named your `IdentityUser` derived class):

```
public class CustomUser : ApplicationUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
}
```

However, you can't use it directly with `Authorize` like your sample code suggests. You would either need to:

1. Do a custom check in your action to verify the user type.
2. Add a role to the user and authorize via that custom role.
3. Create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that checks that the user is the right type

**UPDATE**

When you inherit from `ApplicationUser` you won't get a separate table. EF will add a `Discriminator` column to `dbo.AspNetUsers`, which will have the value of either "ApplicationUser" or "CustomUser", depending on which was saved. EF will then use this column to instantiate the appropriate class when you query users from the database.

One thing to note is that `UserManager` is actually an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. It's a generic class, so whatever user class is specified as the type argument when instantiate will be the class `UserManager` operates on. As a result, if you want to work with `CustomUser`, you will need an instance of `UserManager<CustomUser>`.

Comment: Ok, that's awesome. I'm just not realizing how to save this custom user and authenticate him. I would have a new db table for him with all the CustomUser fields and some of the ApplicationUser fields. Can I create CustomUser and authenticate with the identity UserManager?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have a last question if you don't mind. Do I need to create a new SignInManager to be able to manually authenticate the CustomUser? Or is there a simpler way to do that?